# How to find out which code and imgs are not useful and extra and delete it

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, performance

I have a very messy website with lots of images and unused CSS and JS-s that are just there making my website's performance lower is there some tool like lighthouse that could help me clean my folder from not used images and tell me which code lines are extra?

Answer (score 2):

I think when you build the project, it automatically optimizes your app